# Input button change color after form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, input

I would like to ask if anyone knows how do you change the color of an input that serves as a submit button, after the form submission. I use twitter bootstrap 3 and any approach would be welcomed. The simplest the better though. In my code I have a form filled with:

```
<input class="btn btn-default" onclick="document.getElementById('priceform').submit()" name="filter" type="submit" value="Action" style="width:45%;font-size: 12px">

<input class="btn btn-default" onclick="document.getElementById('priceform').submit()" name="filter" type="submit" value="Adventure" style="width:45%;font-size: 12px">

<input class="btn btn-default" onclick="document.getElementById('priceform').submit()" name="filter" type="submit" value="Family" style="width:45%;font-size: 12px">
```

and many more of the same kind for every game genre there is and they serve as a filter for the results on my product page. Everything works good and I tried to put some color on the button the user applied to filter their results but of course after the form submission the color remains the default. I tried JavaScript, I tried JQuery and still nothing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: button change color on click wont do for you?

Comment: after the form submit somehow it stays as it was.

Comment: i think that's because your page reload when your form is submitted thus the changes by the javascript is reverted. u either have to use session to save the button state or use ajax to submit the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used php super global $_SESSION[ ] to solve this problem. I stored into session the value of the input that was pressed every time and then I applied a style through echoing it.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['filter'])) {
    $_GET['filter'] = $_SESSION['filter'];
    $f = $_GET['filter'];                 
    $filter = "AND type = '$f'";         //ignore this part
    $bool = true;                        //and this
    echo '<style>input[value="'.$f.'"] {
        background-color: #428BCA;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }</style>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding a id tag to the input. Then you can change the color of the background on the selected input.
This is how..

```
function change(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.background = '#999';
}
```

To your input add

```
<input id="action" class="btn btn-default" onclick="document.getElementById('priceform').submit()" onmousedown="change(this.id)" name="filter" type="button" value="Action" style="width:45%;font-size: 12px">
<input id="adventure" class="btn btn-default" onclick="document.getElementById('priceform').submit()"onmousedown="change(this.id)" name="filter" type="button" value="Adventure" style="width:45%;font-size: 12px">
<input id="family" class="btn btn-default" onclick="document.getElementById('priceform').submit()"onmousedown="change(this.id)" name="filter" type="button" value="Family" style="width:45%;font-size: 12px">
```

Add an ID to the input, then add a function that changes the CSS.Access the function with `onmousedown="change(this.id);`

Comment: After form submit it doesn't stay the color I want. I believe the problem is with the submit because it runs the code again.

Comment: @VasilisDaVitzi  After i answered the question, it came to me that maybe you were not using `AJAX.` In that case, yes it will revert back to the original `HTML` and `CSS`. Not sure of the complexity of your program,but would suggest looking at `AJAX` or `Jquery`. makes it easier to expand each page, with user input error catching, page manipulation, etc. Glad you figured your problem out :)

Comment: Thank you James for the time you put to answer me and yes you are right about the Ajax thing. It's only I am new to web development and I try to figure out some things. I'll definately know better next time.